# CSS Grid: width overflowing viewport

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

The css below results in horizontal overflow and a scrollbar. I tried the following: changing the mid-column to `80%`, `80vw`, `200px`, removing the `width` attribute, adding `width: 100vw` to the `<body>`. What am I doing wrong?

Pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyGbpZ

Changing the mid-column fr in the Pen does NOT result in the expected width change. I'd like to understand why.

Also: the text in the bullet list seems to overlay the image on the left. Why is that? They are located in two separate Grid tracks.

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you forget to remove the default margin on the `body`? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Nzrmqj

Comment: This seems to address the problem partially. Interestingly, the body is still around 5px too wide, with a tiny scroll bar below. But aside from this: my two side columns are images, and they simply won't become narrow. I tried now "1fr 10fr 1fr", and the two images take each around 30% of the width. I thought Grid takes care of this automatically. Do I need to define anything on the images? Currently they're not even called in the CSS .

Comment: You really need to demonstrate the **actual problem**.

Comment: Please see Pen above.

Comment: You mean like this? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XYjmVz

Comment: That's certainly more like it! Can I have this explained please? Why do I need to force img width: 100%? I thought the CSS Grid is strict and robust. The width is defined in the grid-template- statements, and all the content fits in. I guess that's not quite true?